# Change the value of Input file (Don't work)

Tags: javascript, count, counter, setvalue

I have a little script which create a new div block if the user click on button. To count how many are created I have an hidden input. Everytime a new block is created the value of this hidden input should get updated.

Thats my script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#addBtn3").on("click", function () {
        imageBlockCount++;
        document.getElementById("counter").value = imageBlockCount;

        $(
            $.parseHTML(
                `<div class="form-group" id="gallery-${imageBlockCount}" >
                <label for="new-content-${imageBlockCount}">New Content</label>
                    <input type="text" name="content-${imageBlockCount}" class="form-control" id="new-content-${imageBlockCount} test-${imageBlockCount}" placeholder="new content" required>
            </div>`
            )
        ).appendTo("#newElements");
    });
});
```

This is my html code:

```
<div style="flex:auto;text-align:right;">
    <button id="addBtn3" type="button">Content +</button> 
</div>

<input name="counter" type="text" id="counter" value="0" hidden>

<div id="newElements">
</div>
```

But in the script where it should update the value don't work, but I don't know why, I don't find any other methods which are so different.

Comment: Your code works for me! place `console.log($("#counter").val())` after appendTo

Comment: Yes but if i press the button and the elemts will be created, i inspect the hidden input and the value is still on 0

Comment: That is default behavior, I post an answer to fix it

Comment: okay thank you im going to wait for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. place `console.log($("#counter").val())` after `appendTo`.

A webpage's HTML doesn't automatically update when an input field's value changes.

If you want such functionality, you could place this after updating value of `#counter`:

```
$('#counter').attr('value', $('#counter').val());
```

```js
$(function () {
  let imageBlockCount = 0
  $("#addBtn3").on("click", function () {
    imageBlockCount++;
    document.getElementById("counter").value = imageBlockCount;
    $('#counter').attr('value', $('#counter').val());
    $(
      $.parseHTML(
        `<div class="form-group" id="gallery-${imageBlockCount}"               <label for="new-content-${imageBlockCount}">New Content</label>
          <input type="text" name="content-${imageBlockCount}" class="form-control" id="new-content-${imageBlockCount} test-${imageBlockCount}" placeholder="new content" required>
        </div>`
      )
    ).appendTo("#newElements");
    console.log($('#counter').val())
  });
});
```

```html
<div style="flex:auto;text-align:right;">
  <button id="addBtn3" type="button">Content +</button> 
</div>
  
<input name="counter" type="text" id="counter" value="0" hidden>
  
<div id="newElements">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes i add this but it still not work. If i write "console.log($("#counter").val())" into the console it returns 0.

Comment: And i add the "$('#counter').attr('value', $('#counter').val());" after update the value still not working

Comment: The update script dont work. I tried this "document.getElementById("counter").value = 1;" and its still not working

Comment: @LazeHo Is there any error in console? add `var imageBlockCount = 0` before click event

Comment: i have let imageBlockCount = 0,

Comment: @LazeHo press `cmd` + `shift` + `r` on mac or  `ctl` + `shift` + `r` on windows to hard refresh the page

Comment: I dont get it your code is the same as mine but yours work my not

Comment: I found the problem all of my scripts are in an js file not in the html file know it works. Is it possible to let the script work the same but in and js file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210888/discussion-between-ashkan-and-laze-ho).